# Does it make sense to use wso2-dss as a data access layer for msf4j microservice?

Tags: wso2-data-services-server, msf4j

My question is related to the architecture of a java microservice with msf4j maria db and wso2 dss, i would like to know is it wise to use the dss as a data access layer , how can i build a correct architecture

Comment: For future references, In SO people want to check your code. Try to avoid asking questions without some resources to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use DSS as the data access layer, you don't need to worry about db connection managing, connection pooling, etc. Otherwise, you will have to write code inside your microservice to manage them. 
I suggest you to use MicroIntegrator profile of WSO2 EI (that has DSS capability) as it suits well with Microservices Architecture.